# Are there any stats that show screen WIDTH instead of DIMENSION?

Tags: website-design, browser, screen-resolution

I am designing a website and have to decide on width of the screen and I need to know the distribution of the screen widths - i.e. **how many people are using screen of width equal or less than X** (= 1024, 1280, ...).

But all I can find is just the distribution of screen dimensions, which is pretty useless for this purpose. It's just a big mess and more importantly, there is always quite big category "Other" which hides all possible screen widths.

So, is there any statistics that shows distribution of just screen widths (not of width x height)?

Comment: I don't understand why the stats are useless. If you can determine that x percent is using a 1280 width or smaller (or whatever) then you have the answer.

Comment: The stats you're looking for is what's known as "browser viewport width". The last detailed report seems to be from 2012. http://beantin.se/computer-screens-browser-viewport-2012/

Comment: @Mayo no you can't. You should have read my question more carefully - see 2nd paragraph, last sentence.

Comment: get any statistics (width by height is way more important that just width, but you'll know) and simply regex `height:(.*?)` if height is such a big deal?           ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2):

W3 counter posted this information Jan. 2017:

```
> Top 10 Screen Resolutions
> 1. 640x360 -  26.54%
> 2. 1366x768 -     13.00%
> 3. 1920x1080 -    5.73%
> 4. 1024x768 -     5.52%
> 5. 667x375 -  4.86%
> 6. 568x320 -  3.52%
> 7. 534x320 -  3.16%
> 8. 1280x800 -     2.73%
> 9. 1280x720 -     2.44%
> 10. 800x600 -     2.30%
```

It doesn't segment the data by mobile or desktop but gives some idea of what's most used. (https://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php)

Or this site: http://gs.statcounter.com/screen-resolution-stats gives data you can edit and play with based on region or device.

Comment: Did you read the title of the question? What you posted is a dimension not width.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/11/screen-resolutions-and-better-user-experience/

> Over 80% will be served well with 1000px screen width, 28% of the users tend to browse with 1250px screen width.

Here is a chart with more in depth statistics:

[image]

This is the results of over 18,000,000 browser screenshots above the fold, so not a complete set of course but should be pretty representative.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but the link is from 2007, which is pretty outdated!